# A Database Error Occurred: this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'cocogrow_office.invoice.date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
SELECT date, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d')) as month, COUNT(invoice_id) as total FROM invoice WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d')) >= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()) GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d')) ORDER BY month ASC
```

```
 //Retrieve Monthly Sales Report
        public function monthly_sales_report() {
            $query1 = $this->db->query("
                SELECT 
                    date,
                    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d')) as month, 
                    COUNT(invoice_id) as total
                FROM 
                    invoice
                WHERE 
                    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d'))  >= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW())
                GROUP BY 
                    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d'))
                ORDER BY
                    month ASC
            ")->result();

            $query2 = $this->db->query("
                SELECT 
                    purchase_date,
                    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM STR_TO_DATE(purchase_date,'%Y-%m-%d')) as month, 
                    COUNT(purchase_id) as total_month
                FROM 
                    product_purchase
                WHERE 
                    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM STR_TO_DATE(purchase_date,'%Y-%m-%d'))  >= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW())
                GROUP BY 
                    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM STR_TO_DATE(purchase_date,'%Y-%m-%d'))
                ORDER BY
                    month ASC
            ")->result();
    //print_r($query1);exit;
            return [$query1, $query2];
        }

        //Retrieve all Report
        public function retrieve_dateWise_SalesReports($from_date, $to_date, $per_page, $page) {
            //  $dateRange = "a.date BETWEEN '$from_date%' AND '$to_date%'";
            $this->db->select("a.*,b.*");
            $this->db->from('invoice a');
            $this->db->join('customer_information b', 'b.customer_id = a.customer_id');
            $this->db->where('a.date >=', $from_date);
            $this->db->where('a.date <=', $to_date);
            $this->db->order_by('a.date', 'desc');
            $this->db->limit($per_page, $page);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                return $query->result_array();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Please only post one query that doesn't run. We don't need any PHP code if your question is just about the SQL error. You should also explain what exactly the query should return.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel am getting a Error Number: 1055

Answer (score 0):

Your server is so configured that it only allows selecting group by column or Columns with [Aggregate (GROUP BY) Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

So Do something like this

```
 SELECT 
   Min(date) date,
   EXTRACT(MONTH FROM STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d')) as month, 
   COUNT(invoice_id) as total
 FROM 
   invoice
 WHERE 
   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d'))  >= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW())
 GROUP BY 
   EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d'))
 ORDER BY
   month ASC;
```

This woold give you the lowest date of the Month for the column date.
the same is also true for your second Select  where you have to put purchase_date in such an Aggregate function.

Comment: Note that though ligically MONTH is finctionally dependent on YEAR_MONTH for the same year, the engine doesn't know that. You should use `GROUP BY month`. Also - you can use `MONTH(date) as month`.